# Can you run a GitHub Action whenever a secret is created/updated/deleted?

Tags: github, triggers, github-actions, github-secret

Is there a way to trigger the run of a GitHub Action when a secret is added/updated/deleted in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

There is no secrets on the list of [events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows), neither [webhook events and payloads](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#create).